# Angular change custom component height

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-components, angular-library

I have a library of which I am trying to use a component from which contains a table. What I am trying to do is to change the height of the component.

So to summarize I can't change the height of the lib-table element.

Component

```
<div class"table-wrap">
 <table>
  ...
 </table>
</div>
```

App.html

```
<lib-table class"height"></lib-table>
```

App.Css

```
.height {
 height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this issue you have to put the class `.table-wrap {}` in your global css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a div like this:

```
<div class"height">
    <lib-table ></lib-table>
</div>
```